À quoi ressemble un « style » au sens propre ?
Je peine à trouver une illustration/image d'un « style », dans le sens propre du mot :

Un style est un poinçon permettant d'écrire en gravant de l'écorce, de la cire, de l'écaille. (Wiktionnaire)

Ce mot signifioit autrefois l’aiguille dont on se servoit pour écrire sur les tablettes enduites de cire. Cette aiguille étoit pointue par un bout, & applatie par l’autre, pour effacer quand on le vouloit : c’est ce qui a fait dire à Horace, sæpe stylum vertas, effacez souvent. (L'encyclopédie, 1re édition)

Poinçon généralement de métal ou d'os, utilisé dans l'Antiquité et au Moyen Âge pour écrire sur des tablettes enduites de cire. (TLFi)



Ce style est aujourd'hui plus souvent appelé stylet.

Renverse, ô scribe, sur la table des grèves, du revers de ton style la cire empreinte du mot vain.
